# Replacing selected text in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I am selecting text using SelectText method in my string.
I want to replace this text but only the selected area. When I use Replace method, it replaces all words in the string. (e.g This Computer is a good Computer.  I only selected last Computer and want to say, This computer is a goods machine.)
It does This machine is a good machine, which I donot want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TextBox1.SelectionStart = 24
TextBox1.SelectionLength = 8

TextBox1.Paste("machine")
```

Answer (score 1):

can you look at SelectionStart and SelectionLength, cut out what you want to replace, then insert what you want.

Comment: Could you kindly give me statement for cutting and inserting?